# Set user-agent property in https connection header

Tags: java, https, http-headers

I am unable to properly set the `user-agent` property for an https connection. From what I've gathered, http-header properties can be set through either the `-Dhttp.agent` VM option or through [`URLConnection.setRequestProperty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setRequestProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). However, setting the user-agent through the VM option causes " Java/[version]" to be appended to whatever the value of http.agent is. At the same time `setRequestProperty()` only works for http connections, not https (at least when I tried it).

```
java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL( "https://www.google.com" );
java.net.URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0");
conn.connect();
java.io.BufferedReader serverResponse = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
System.out.println(serverResponse.readLine());
serverResponse.close();
```

I've found/verified the problem by inspecting http communictions using WireShark. Is there any way around this?

**Update: Addition Info**

It seems that I didn't look deep enough into the communication. The code is running from behind a proxy so the communication observed is against the proxy, set through `-Dhttps.proxyHost`, and not the target website (google.com). Anyway, during an https connection, the method is `CONNECT`, not `GET`. Here is a wireshark capture of https communication attempt. Like I mentioned above, the user-agent is set through `-Dhttp.agent` because `URLConnection.setRequestProperty()` has no effect (user-agent = Java/1.7.0). In this case, notice the appended *Java/1.7.0*. The question remains the same, why is this happening and how do I get around it?

```
CONNECT www.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 Java/1.7.0
Host: www.google.com
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
X-Bst-Request-Id: MWPwwh:m7d:39175
X-Bst-Info: ch=req,t=1366218861,h=14g,p=4037_7213:1_156,f=PEFilter,r=PEBlockCatchAllRule,c=1905,v=7.8.14771.200 1363881886
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Pragma: No-cache
Content-Language: en
Cache-Control: No-cache
Content-Length: 2491
```

By the way, the request is forbidden because the proxy filters user-agent, the *Java/1.7.0* is causing the rejection. I've appended *Java/1.7.0* to the user-agent of an http connection and the proxy refuses connection too. I hope i'm not going crazy :).

Comment: I'm not seeing the behavior you describe.  Using your code block (and changing the url) my access log shows:  [11/Apr/2013:18:35:05 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 17353 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0" "-".  This request was also over https, using OS X.

Comment: @JasonNichols I'm running Windows XP with Java 1.7.0_17

Comment: How about using HttpClient?

Comment: @Vitaly I'm actually trying to test webservice connection using netbeans when I came across this problem. Using HttpClient would be last resort.

Comment: Just tried this on java 7 and was able to set the headers and extract the content too. Response - `<!doctype html><html itemscope="itemscope" itemtype= ...`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I've found/verified the problem by inspecting http communictions using WireShark. Is there any way around this

This is not possible. Communication over an SSL socket is completely obscured from casual observation by the encryption protocol. Using packet capture software you will be able to view the initiation of the SSL connection and the exchange of encrypted packets, but the content of those packets can only be extracted at the other end of the connection (the server). If this were not the case then the HTTPS protocol as a whole would be *broken*, as the whole point of it is to secure HTTP communications from man-in-the-middle type attacks (where in this case the MITM is the packet sniffer).

#### Example Capture of an HTTPS request (partial):

> .n....E... .........../..5..3..9..2..8..
>   ..............@........................Ql.{...b....OsR..!.4.$.T...-.-.T....Q...M..Ql.{...LM..L...um.M...........s. ...n...p^0}..I..G4.HK.n......8Y...............E...A..>...0...0.........
>   ).s.......0
>   ..*.H..
>   .....0F1.0...U....US1.0...U.
>   .
>   Google Inc1"0 ..U....Google Internet Authority0..
>   130327132822Z.
>   131231155850Z0h1.0...U....US1.0...U...
>   California1.0...U...
>   Mountain View1.0...U.
>   .
>   Google Inc1.0...U....www.google.com0..0

Theoretically, the only way to know if your `User-Agent` header is actually being excluded is if you have access to the Google servers, but in actuality there is nothing in either the HTTPS specification or Java's implementation of it that excludes headers that would normally have been sent over HTTP.

#### Example Capture of HTTP request:

> GET / HTTP/1.1
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0
>   Host: www.google.com
>   Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
>   Connection: keep-alive

Both example captures were generated with the ***exact*** same code:

```
URL url = new URL(target);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0");
conn.connect();
BufferedReader serverResponse = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
System.out.println(serverResponse.readLine());
serverResponse.close();
```

Except that for HTTPS the target was "https://www.google.com", and for HTTP it was "http://www.google.com".

---

### Edit 1:

Based off your updated question, using the `-Dhttp.agent` property ***does indeed*** append 'Java/version' to the user agent header, as described by the [following documentation](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html):

> *http.agent* (default: “Java/<version>”)
>   Defines the string sent in the User-Agent request header in http requests. Note that the string “Java/<version>” will be appended to the one provided in the property (e.g. if -Dhttp.agent=”foobar” is used, the User-Agent header will contain “foobar Java/1.5.0” if the version of the VM is 1.5.0). This property is checked only once at startup.

The 'offending' code is in a static block initializer of `sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection`:

```
static {
    // ...
    String agent = java.security.AccessController
            .doPrivileged(new sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction(
                    "http.agent"));
    if (agent == null) {
        agent = "Java/" + version;
    } else {
        agent = agent + " Java/" + version;
    }
    userAgent = agent;

    // ...
}
```

An obscene way around this 'problem' is this snippet of code, which I 1000% recommend you ***not*** use:

```
protected void forceAgentHeader(final String header) throws Exception {
    final Class<?> clazz = Class
            .forName("sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection");

    final Field field = clazz.getField("userAgent");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
    modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
    modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
    field.set(null, header);
}
```

Using this override with `https.proxyHost`, `https.proxyPort` and `http.agent` set gives the desired result:

> CONNECT www.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0
>   Host: www.google.com
>   Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
>   Proxy-Connection: keep-alive

But yea, don't do that. Its much safer to just use [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/):

```
final DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("127.0.0.1", 8888, "http");
HttpHost target = new HttpHost("www.google.com", 443, "https");
client.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);
HttpProtocolParams
        .setUserAgent(client.getParams(),
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0");
final HttpGet get = new HttpGet("/");

HttpResponse response = client.execute(target, get);
```

Comment: Thanks for the info but I think I've led you astray, sorry. Your comment about not being able to see SSL header led me to look over the issue again. I've updated my question.

Comment: @user845279 - ok, your question is clearer now with the added information. I've added some information to my answer about ***why*** this is happening.

Comment: Awesome. Your answer is good enough already, but I'm hoping you could help me with one more thing. Why can't I set the value through `URLConnection.setRequestProperty()`? Can you suggest a workaround for me? Thx

Comment: @user845279 - The setRequestProperty does work, but then the Sun secure socket implementation explicitly overrides the User-Agent header as part of its code, to whatever is set in -Dhttp.agent + Java/<version> appended. I'm still tracing the code but it looks like it will only do this when a proxy is being used. Unfortunately there is no direct workaround.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I've submitted a bug report to Oracle. [Bug Id: 9001759](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=9001759)

Answer (score 0):

> I've found/verified the problem by inspecting http communictions using WireShark. Is there any way around this?

There is no problem here. The User-Agent header is set whether the request is transported via HTTP / HTTPS. Even setting it to something unreasonable like `blah blah` works on HTTPS. The headers shown below were captured when the underlying protocol used was **HTTPS**.

## Request headers sent via HTTPS

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Connection: keep-alive
```

---

```
User-Agent: blah blah
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Connection: keep-alive
```

---

Here's the code that triggers the request.

```
        // localhost:52999 is a reverse proxy to xxx:443
        java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL( "https://localhost:52999/" );
        java.net.URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0");
        conn.connect();
        java.io.BufferedReader serverResponse = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println(serverResponse.readLine());
        serverResponse.close();
```

Normally, HTTPS requests cannot be sniffed (like @Perception mentioned). Piping the request through a proxy that replaces the root CA with its own fake CA will allow you to see the traffic. A simpler method is to just look at the access log of the target server. But as you can see from the HTTPS request snippet above, the `User-Agent` header that is sent is correct.