# JSoup Connection.userAgent defeated by sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, jsoup, user-agent, httpconnection

Apparently, sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection will always append "Java/version" to the UserAgent. Therefore, JSoup Connection.userAgent cannot set the useragent to what you want; the "Java/version" stuff gets appended anyway.

See [Set user-agent property in https connection header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15845075/set-user-agent-property-in-https-connection-header)

Some websites reject requests that contain "Java" anywhere in
the user agent, giving various 4xx and 5xx HTTP errors.

The StackOverflow post referenced above suggests using Apache instead of Sun's HTTP connection class, but this is not an option if I want to use JSoup.

I wonder what the JSoup team thinks of this. Is my description correct? Is it a bug or a feature? Are there any plans to fix it, i.e. to make it possible to set the userAgent to what one wants, without additional appendages?

thanks
JWG

Answer (score 0):

You could use Jsoup.parse(html) where the html String could be fetched using Apache HTTP or any other library of your choice. 
Regards,
Allahbaksh